# Algorithm for Fundamental theorem of arithmetic

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

What is a good algorithm for decomposing a number into a product of primes? What would be its time complexity?

Comment: Google: prime factorization algorithm. (use DuckDuckGo.com for more privacy)

Comment: mmm I guess its running time is rather not that great.

Comment: @kolonel: Good guess. The best known algorithm (in my answer) is a lot faster than trial division but still not that fast.

Answer (score 4):

The best known algorithm for factorization is the General Number Field Sieve which runs in time roughly $(\log n)^{C(\log n)^{1/3}(\log\log n)^{2/3}}$.

This is much, much faster than trial division. For example, a hundred-digit number can be factored in about a day with this method, compared to $10^{33}$ years for trial division.

Still, a practical approach will combine a bit of trial division with a bit of searching for small factors with ECM before moving to NFS.

Answer (score 3):

There is a whole branch of cryptography that relies on the notion that there is not really a "good" algorithm that can decompose any arbitrary number into prime factors.  That is, someone who wants to encrypt some data will choose a number that is the product of very large primes, and there is no known algorithm to extract those primes from their product in any reasonable amount of time.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439870/why-are-primes-important-in-cryptography

Also see [Algorithms for Finding the Prime Factorization of an Integer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/631559/algorithms-for-finding-the-prime-factorization-of-an-integer), which I think is the same question as this one.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.alpertron.com.ar/ECM.HTM) site, for instance, implements the [elliptic curve method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra_elliptic_curve_factorization). It is pretty quick, as you can see, but by no means the fastest. That would be the [general number field sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve). More information can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization#Current_state_of_the_art). Hope this helps.