# Divisibility by a prime number and multiplicity

Tags: divisibility

We want to determine the number of times a prime number $p$ divides a number $n$ or, in other words, determine the greatest integer $k$ such that $p^k\ |\ n$.

Is there a better method than trying naive division successively?

Comment: Do ask about actual numerical computation for large ingers? Here the repeated division can very time-consuming. MP libraries use a strategy with increasing powers of $p$, see e.g. the Gnu MP function mpz_remove (remove.c)

Comment: @gammatester Thanks for your comment, but is "computing successive powers of $p$ and testing division for each power" really less time consuming than "simply testing successive division by $p$"?

Comment: I did **not** say "computing successive powers of p". Actually the simple idea is something like this:

From $i=0$ keep on dividing by ascending powers $p^{2^i}$ until a non-zero remainder is found (while storing these powers, note that the next power is just a squaring), then divide by the stored descending powers giving a zero remainder.

Comment: @gammatester Sorry, you are right that was obvious. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In general, there are several [integer factorization algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization), which are sometimes better than just naive division. See also [this MSE-question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/631559/algorithms-for-finding-the-prime-factorization-of-an-integer).
For some integers, there is an explicit formula for the multiplicity, e.g., for $n=N!$. In fact,
the highest power of a prime $p$ dividing $N!$ is given by

$$\nu_p(N!) = \left \lfloor \frac{N}{p} \right \rfloor + \left \lfloor \frac{N}{p^2} \right \rfloor + \left \lfloor \frac{N}{p^3} \right \rfloor + \cdots$$

The main difficulty often is to find *any* prime dividing our integer $n$. For example, which prime divides
$
n=1167984798111281975972139931059274579165801700195500732513291383783133049$ $58815197564537037428785261488414688806744251221941374876801065757257538498$ 
$6457405973985247465176041951676954461208131403777$

Once you have discovered that
$$
p=2^{127}-1
$$
is a prime divisor, it is easy to see that $p^2$ does not divide $n$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In fact, my $n$ is an arbitrary number, and not the factorial of a number. What do you mean by MSE? Thank you again

Comment: MSE is this site here, called Mathematics StackExchange.

Comment: Oups sorry :-/ . Thank you.